# Parse dictionaries within a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tree

I am pretty much struck in this for a while,

I have a dictionary

```
tree = {
    'B': {
        '1': {
            'E': {
                '1': {
                    'D': {
                        '1': '1',
                        '0': '0'
                         }
                     },
                '0': {
                    'A': {
                        '1': '0',
                        '0': '1'
                         }
                     }
                 }
             },
          '0': '1'
       }
    }
```

I am trying to parse through it and get the number of alphabets in the dictionary. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thank you!!

Comment: What do you mean, "the number of alphabets?" for the sample input in the question, what's the expected output?

Comment: Consider formatting that code to make it clearer what's nested where.

Comment: I am trying to get the number of alphabets, for the above example, the number would be: 4

Comment: Where did this data structure come from?

Comment: I am trying to build a tree, the dictionary values will help me build one. And the Alphabets are the nodes of the tree

Comment: `s/alphabet/alphabetic character/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution, using loops + recursion:

```
def traverse(tree):
    if not isinstance(tree, dict):
        return tree.isalpha() # if leafs can't be alphabetic, simply return 0
    c = 0
    for k, v in tree.items():
        c += k.isalpha() + traverse(v)
    return c
```

Or a bit shorter, using generator expressions + recursion:

```
def traverse(tree):
    if not isinstance(tree, dict):
        return tree.isalpha() # if leafs can't be alphabetic, simply return 0
    return sum(k.isalpha() + traverse(v) for k, v in tree.items())
```

Either way, it works. For example, using the input in the question:

```
tree = {'B': {'0': '1',
              '1': {'E': {'0': {'A': {'0': '1', '1': '0'}},
                          '1': {'D': {'0': '0', '1': '1'}}}}}}
traverse(tree)
=> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this:

```
>>> tree = {'B': {'1': {'E': {'1': {'D': {'1': '1', '0': '0'}}, '0': {'A': {'1': '0', '0': '1'}}}}, '0': '1'}}
>>> print len(filter(lambda ch: ch.isalpha(), str(tree)))
4
```